# I need help in developing a circular pattern

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to generate this pattern and instead of adding `for loops` and approximate angles (I think the angles towards the end might be off). I was wondering if someone could provide some insight into generating this pattern with less code.

**The end goal would be to simply state the radius and how many layers of circles i wish to generate**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

__author__ = 'George Pamfilis'

def rotate_around_origin(r,angle):
    # http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PolarCoordinates.aspx
    x = r * np.cos(angle)
    y = r * np.sin(angle)
    return x, y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = 1
    r_cylinder = 1
    p1 = (0, 0)
    ps = [p1]

angle = 60

# first layer
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(2*r + (r/2) * 0, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60

# second layer


angle = 30

for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(3*r+(r/2) * 1, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(4*r+(r/2)*0, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60 + 30/2 + 4

for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(5*r+(r/3), np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60 +30/2 + 4 -8 + 30

for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(5*r+(r/3), np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(5*r+(r/1)*1, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60

angle = 30
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(6 * r + (r / 1) * 1, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60 +13.75
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(6*r+(r/1)*1+r/4, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 46.25
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(6*r+(r/1)*1+r/4, np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


angle = 60
for i in range(6):
    p_new = rotate_around_origin(6*r+(r/1)*1+r/4 + (r/1.25), np.deg2rad(angle))
    ps.append(p_new)
    angle += 60


plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20 * (1/1)))

fig = plt.gcf()
# circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6*r+r+r+r/2+r, color="r")
# this is added just to enclose the pattern.
circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6*r+r+r+r, color="r")

fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
for p in ps:
    circle1 = plt.Circle((p[0], p[1]), r)
    fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)


plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Okay.... so what is your question? I see a problem statement and a code dump.

Comment: the problem statement "states" <instead of adding for loops and approximate angles (i think the angles towards the end might be off) i was wondering if someone could provide some insight>. and the title asks for a pattern

Comment: Why bother with all of those rotations? You're building a hexagonal grid of circles, so the horizontal coordinates of the circles' centres are all whole multiples of the circle radius, and the vertical coordinates are all sqrt(3) times whole multiples of that radius.

Answer (score 1):

find small circle radius for given big R and number of layers (rings including central small circle)

find number of horizontal layers

for every horizontal layer calculate the first and  the last small circle position

Working Delphi example:

```
var
  cx, cy, R, NL, irs: Integer;
  rs, yshift, dx: Double;
  iymax, ix, iy, mx, my, il, ir, Nl4: Integer;
begin
  R := 180;
  NL := 8;
  cx := 200;
  cy := 200;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Ellipse(cx - R, cy - R, cx + R + 1, cy + R + 1);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;

  rs := R / (2 * NL - 1); // small radius
  irs := Round(rs); // integer radius for drawing
  Nl4 := 4 * (NL - 1) * (NL - 1);
  iymax := Floor((2 * NL - 2) / Sqrt(3)); // horizontal layers from center to top

  for iy := -iymax to iymax do
  begin
    yshift := iy * Sqrt(3) * rs; // relative to center
    my := cy + Round(yshift); // y-coordinate

    // find left small circle inside big one
    if Odd(iy) then
    begin
      il := Floor(0.5 * Sqrt(Nl4 - 3 * iy * iy) + 0.5);
      dx := rs;
      ir := 1;
    end
    else
    begin
      il := Floor(0.5 * Sqrt(Nl4 - 3 * iy * iy));
      dx := 0;
      ir := 0;
    end;

    for ix := -il to il - ir do
    begin
      mx := cx + Round(ix * 2 * rs + dx);
      Canvas.Ellipse(mx - irs, my - irs, mx + irs + 1, my + irs + 1);
    end;
  end;
```

[image]